# CSS Works in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I've been working on a school project and i've made this layout quickly and I have no idea why this layout works perfectly on Chrome but crashes completly in Firefox! Does anybody have an idea what it could be?

Here is the site:
www.demo.filipsukic.com

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Without **CODE** no **IDEA**
No One can Help You without CODE..

Comment: Im working on putting the code up but its hard since ive got my own prototype framework.  i hoped that a browsers developer tools woud be enough.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For a quick fix, add the class "clearfix" to all your section tags.

Answer (score 0):

This may fix your problem.

Make sure that the type on your stylesheets needs to

be like:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

not like:

```
<link type="/text/css" href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Removing the / at the beginning.